# Google Chroome - Enable USB debugging on tablet kitkat 4.4

Tags: android

Sorry if this seems like a stupid question but I just can not figure it out!

I am trying to setup Remote Debugging on Android for google Chrome on a new tablet which is loaded with kitkat 4.4.

According to the documentation On Android 4.2 and newer, Developer options is hidden by default. To make it available, go to Settings > About phone and tap Build number seven times.

The problem I have is that there is no "About phone" or even "About"- so I resorted to trying tapping most items on the settings seven times but still can not get developers options.

[image: Scrrenshot]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? Usually you can capture with the power button and volume down or volume up, or downloading an application to do it (though that may get in the way) of your tablet settings menu? It usually appears near the bottom.

Comment: Sounds like you might have an off-brand tablet or at least one without standard Android.  It's possible adb is already on, or even not supported.  But try looking for an information screen in settings.  And try a *web search* on the tablet brand, model, or style in combination with "adb".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this from http://www.modaco.com/topic/365530-how-to-root-your-hudl-updated-latest-supported-rom-20131016200812/page-3

> Go to app drawer and open Settings
>    Go to bottom and tap About tablet
>    Tap repeatedly Build number 7 times. Starting at 3rd tap, you'll see a toast saying You are now X steps away from being a developer.
>      After 7th tap, you should get a toast saying: You are now a developer! (If you keep tapping Build number, the toast will change to: No need, you are already a developer.)
>
> Next, go back to Settings, and at the bottom you'll see:
>       {} Developer options
>   You'll find USB Debugging in there

Comment: Many thanks Shia - my problem was that I was trying to do it in Chrome setup rather than the table setup!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes there is more than one setting available in Android OS.
Go to desktop (via Home Button) and push the Menu Button. There will be a list for "General, App, System Settings)
Maybe it helps to know what Tablet is exactly used (Brand, Model, Series..)

Comment: The tablet is a Tesco hudl 2

Comment: Good point.  Samsung for example seems to have two distinct settings menus.